# How to Add a Print Button on Infopath 2010 List Form

Tags: infopath, list-form, printing

I have a list with an InfoPath form published to it. I have a request to have a print button functionality added.

I have seen that on Form Libraries this was doable but how about a List Form?

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot have code for List form instead we can have for Library form.

but you can try to

- add a InfoPath form web part and place the InfoPath list form on that web part.
- add a content editor web part with the following func to reference the form (div) directly:

`function printInfoPathForm(){
         var ipForm = $(INFOPATH_FORM);
            if (ipForm) {
                //build html for print page
                var html = "<HTML><HEAD>\n"+
                    $("head").html()+
                    "</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n"+
                    ipForm.html()+
                    "\n</BODY></HTML>";
                //open new window
                var printWP = window.open("","printWebPart");
                printWP.document.open();
                //insert content
                printWP.document.write(html);
                printWP.document.close();
                //open print dialog
                printWP.print();
            }
        }`

You can also check

- https://arcemise.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/sharepoint-2010-infopath-print-button/
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/print-button-on-infopath-form-in-sharepoint-2010/