# How to add a print button on InfoPath

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath

Is there a way to add a print button on InfoPath just like submit and cancel button??

I know a way to add using JavaScript I was hoping to know if there is another way on InfoPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no out-of-the-box print button in InfoPath.

**The available options**

- To add a script editor to your page and add custom print button `<input type="button" value=" Print this page " onclick="window.print();return false;" />`
- Use custom Action print button as mentioned at http://infopathprinter.codeplex.com/
- using `thisXDocument.PrintOut()` to infopath button code as mentioned at [Creating a 'Print' Button or printing on submit](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/2041/32559.aspx)
- Or using Javascript as I have answered at [How to Add a Print Button on Infopath 2010 List Form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/187927/how-to-add-a-print-button-on-infopath-2010-list-form/187930#187930)

Comment: You are welcome, In case it helped you please don't forget to mark this answer and upvote it to help future visitors. :)

Comment: I already did it !

Comment: thank you, but the Mark as answer is the true sign beside my answer thanks again :)  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour